# Get iframe contents with a jquery selector

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors, sizzle

Is there anyway to access an iframe's contents via a selector?  Something like this:

```
$("iframe::contents .my-foo")
```

I'm constantly accessing an iframe's contents for a project I'm currently working on and `$("iframe").contents().find(".my-foo")` is becoming a bit tedious to type out.

If this feature doesn't exist in jquery out of the box, is there a plugin that provides this functionality?  If not how could I write such a plugin?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this issue once where I found it tedious. I never found a solution for how to write a single selector like that.

Even so, the selector is still rather long. The most obvious solution to me is just save it to a variable.

```
var frame = $("iframe").contents();

frame.find(".my-foo")
...
```

Is that better?

Comment: Some More Info - `contents()` = `children()` +  `plaintext` . Some may be thinking what is the use of `contents()` when we could just use `$('iframe').find('.my-foo')`, then please read `The contents() method can also access the HTML of an iframe, if it is in the same domain.` from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_contents.asp

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, it seems more elegant to pack everything into the one selector, but the truth is that, even if there were such a selector, it is better from a performance perspective to traverse with find(). Then jQuery doesn't have to parse and analyze the string.

Answer (score 1):

Added here for posterity.  The solution I ended up going with was to override the root jquery object with a bit of custom parsing code.  Something like this:

```
(function() {
    var rootjq = window.jQuery;

    var myjq = function(selector, context) {
        if(selector.indexOf("::contents") === -1) {
            return rootjq(selector, context);
        } else {
            var split = selector.split("::contents");

            var ifrm = split[0];
            var subsel = split.splice(1).join("::contents");

            var contents = rootjq(ifrm, context).contents();

            // Recursive call to support multiple ::contents in a query
            return myjq(subsel, contents);
        }
    };
    myjq.prototype = myjq.fn = rootjq.fn;

    window.jQuery = window.$ = myjq;
})();
```

Note that double colon (`::`) in css means [select pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704049), while single colon means select by pseudo class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom selector. Like:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    contents: function(elem, i, attr){
      return $(elem).contents().find( attr[3] );
    }
});
```

Usage should be like

```
$('iframe:contents(.my-foo)').remove();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why are using `$.extend`? Why not add the property directly like this: `$.expr[":"].contents = function(...) { ... }`?

Comment: This answer doesn't work.  I was looking for a replacement of `$("iframe").contents().find(".my-foo")`.  Functions hanging off of `$.expr[':']` act like filters.