# What does the double colon (::) mean in CSS?

Tags: css

What does the double colon (`::`) mean in CSS?

For example:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

It means *pseudo element* selector. It means the *element* to the right doesn't exist in the normal DOM, but can be selected.

> A pseudo-element is made of two colons (::) followed by the name of the pseudo-element.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements)

It was originally only a single colon, but was changed to differentiate it from *pseudo classes* (like `:hover`, `:first-child`, `:not` etc). It's best to use `:` for `before` and `after` pseudo elements since the single colon has better browser support, namely in earlier IE versions.

Answer (score 33):

The `::` operator indicates you are selecting a *pseudo element*, one which does not actually exist as an element but can still be targeted for styling.

Example of this include several vendor-specific implementations such as the `-ms-clear` sample you provide, most browsers also have pseudo elements to style scroll bars and other native UI elements, but there are also a lot of [predefined pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) which can be referenced for practical reasons, such as `first-line` and `first-letter`.

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements even allow you to insert actual content into the page using CSS with the `content` rule.

Answer (score 13):

CSS3 changes the way pseudo-elements are selected, as the W3C wanted to distinguish pseudo-classes like `a:visited` from pseudo-elements like `p::first-line`.  See [Advanced CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors#CSS3_pseudo-element_double_colon_syntax).