# What does it mean this sass code?

Tags: css, sass

I'm newbie at sass and I've a lot of lines like this:

```
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: $topright;
-moz-border-radius-topright: $topright;
```

and

```
&::-webkit-input-placeholder {@content}
&:-moz-placeholder           {@content}
```

I don't know what are those names that start with a "-" and I want to know what "&:" and "&::" mean.

Thanks

Comment: Those names that start with a '-' are called vendor prefixes: http://davidwalsh.name/vendor-prefixes

Comment: Thanks you ;) I learnt that, e.g. `&:after`, it's the sass way to write pseudo-elements but I don't know what means those two: `&:` and `&..`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of those are sass code.

The `-webkit` and `-moz` prefixes are vendor specific styles. Those are non-standard styles that apply to the Webkit and Mozilla engines, used by Safari and Firefox.

There are no `&:` and `&::` selectors, the `&` is just the regualar sass [parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-script) and the `:` and `::` is part of the `:-moz-placeholder` pseudo-class and the `::-webkit-input-placeholder` pseudo element.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a parent's selector.
For example:

```
div {
    background: red;
    &.blue {
       background: blue !important;
    }
    &:hover {
       background: transparent;
    }
}
```

It is compiled to:

```css
div { 
    background: red;
}
div.blue {
    background: blue !important;
}
div:hover {
    background: transparent;
}
```

You can see the documentation: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector

The `:` or `::` is a pseudo-element. In this case to set the style for the placeholder attribute.

See examples here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-css3-placeholder-pseudo-element

`-` is a vendor prefix like @xbonez has said in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: $topright; 
-moz-border-radius-topright: $topright;
```

here - $topright is a variable with some css value like $topright : 10px;

then converted to css

```
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;


&::-webkit-input-placeholder {@content}
&:-moz-placeholder           {@content}
```

`::` is a is a pseudo-selector with inner element like anchor

```
a{
 &::after{

 }
}
```

will become

```
a:after{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`-moz-border-radius-topright` is simply a vendor specific property for Mozilla browsers, to support properties before they were in the actual standard (and the standard was published). There are [several more vendor prefixes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#vendor-keyword-history) such as`moz`, `webkit`, `o` (opera)

`&` in sass (also in less) means "the selector of the parent scope" (`:` and `::` just denote [pseudo-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16704049/112968), nothing sass-specific here, that's normal css). For instance:

```
a {
  color:blue;
  &:hover {
    color:red;
  }
}
```

Gets translated into

```
a { color:blue; }
a:hover { color:red; }
```

Comment: Thanks you ;) @knittl, for both anwsers

Answer (score 0):

The '-' is actually part of CSS. They are used to indicate vendor prefixes which are used for new CSS features that are not yet part of the formal CSS specification. More info - http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm

The '&' character is used in SASS to refer to the parent selector. More info - http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector

The following SASS code:

```
div {
    color: red;
    &:hover {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

Will compile to the following CSS:

```
div {
    color: red;
}
div:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

The ':' and '::' characters are used to select pseudo-elements - see http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors#Pseudo-elements