# a small python crawler puzzle

Tags: python, css, css-selectors

My code:

```
import requests
from parsel import Selector


url = 'https://www.vmall.com/product/10086763808943.html?cid=99844'
resp = requests.get(url)
# print(resp.text)
sel = Selector(resp.text)
res = sel.css('#pro-name::text').extract()
print(res)
```

Who can explain `res = sel.css('#pro-name::text').extract()`? Why do we use double `":"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the double colon (::) mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704049/what-does-the-double-colon-mean-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

That line is CSS styling if I understand correctly. A similar question was asked previously:

[What does the double colon (::) mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704049/what-does-the-double-colon-mean-in-css)